# Extraer datos de un while con una variable

Tags: php, array, variables, while

tengo un archivo desde donde manejo todos los datos asociados a alertas y otras cosas al que llamo config.php, ahora este archivo me lleva todas las variables a mi index.php a traves de un include'', el problema es que necesito hacer un while desde config.php pero imprimirlo en index.php y no lo he podido lograr

mi arreglo es más o menos así:

```
while($rdes = mysqli_fetch_array($query3)){
    
$nombre = $rdes['nombre'];
$telefono = $rdes['telefono'];
    
    if (mysql_num_row($query3) == 0) 
        {$resultados = 'Sin resultados';    }
        else
        {$resultados = 'Nombre:'.$nombre.' y telefono '.$telefono.'</br>';';}   }
```

Ahora cuando imprimo la variable $resultados en mi archivo index.php, lo hago asi `echo $resultados` solamente me trae el último registro pero no los demás, hasta donde he podido investigar es porque no puedo extraer la información de mi arreglo en una variable como lo estoy haciendo.

Alguien puede ayudarme por favor, explicandome si puedo hacer lo que pretendo?

Desde ya gracias.

Comment: En lugar de `mysql_num_row` debe ser `mysqli_num_rows`.

Answer (score 0):

El problema se debe a que, en cada iteración, estas pisando el valor de la variable `$resultados`.

#### Solución:

Necesitas usar el [operador de asignación sobre concatenación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.string.php) (`.=`)

**Ejemplo:**

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($query3) == 0) {
    $resultados = 'Sin resultados';
} else {

    $resultados = '';
    while($rdes = mysqli_fetch_array($query3)){

        $nombre = $rdes['nombre'];
        $telefono = $rdes['telefono'];

        // ACA usamos el operador para concatenar
        $resultados .= 'Nombre:'.$nombre.' y telefono '.$telefono.'</br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, lo utilice con la concatenación como me recomiendas, lo hice tal cual, pero al al imprimir la la variable en mi index.php me sale el mensaje Notice: Undefined variable: resultados in ... , es decir como si no reconociera esa variable, que podrá ser?

Comment: Eso es porque no has inicializado la variable antes de empezar a concatenar.